# FTP login using Shell class in VBScript stopped working after changing credentials

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I had a Windows server uploading certain files to a web server using VBScript for a few years now with no issues. I now moved my website to a new server and for some reason the script stopped working...the below excerpt throws an error *"Object required"* for instance:

```
strFTP = "ftp://" & strFTPUser & ":" & strFTPPass & "@" & strFTPHost & strFTPDir
Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)

'Make new folder on FTP site
objFTP.NewFolder "FTP Backup"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Error after FTP create: " & Err.Description
End If
```

I only changed the login variables so I'm guessing something is differently configured on the new server. Can someone suggest what to do? Lots of cron type services depend on this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a `@` in a username, which has a special meaning in an URL (separator of credentials and a hostname), you need to [URL-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it to `%40`:

```
strFTPUser = "user%40domain"
```

Comment: thank you...that was it....it didn't occur to me the @ sign would be a problem, but when you think it's part of the server address it makes sense...